# Why do .htaccess redirects work in http but not with https?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

I have a simple .htaccess file that works great on the http version of the site but not when I go to https. Why?

```
RewriteEngine on
#This is so if the file exists then use the file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME} [L]

#These conditions check if a file or folder exists just for reference
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#if someone adds ".php" to the slug get rid of it
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1  

#don't add the [R] here because we don't want it to redirect
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's not 100% enough info here to go on, but in the usual default SSL setup (Red Hat/CentOS/Fedora e.g.) the VirtualHost for SSL is set up in it's own container. The use of mod_rewrite requires at a minimum "AllowOverride FileInfo" to be set on the document root for it to act.

Check your config for SSL (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf by default), ensure that it looks something like:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
<Directory /var/www/html>
  AllowOverride FileInfo
</Directory>
```

The default for AllowOverride is 'None', so any other setting (such as 'All') which adds FileInfo capabilities is OK.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: I can't see /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf in my linux, how to find it ?

Comment: (1) You might need to search for the conf file.. For example, on some systems it's `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf` (2) To be super-clear, if you're still having issues, try `AllowOverride All` instead of `AllowOverride FileInfo`. Once you get it working, you can read the Apache `AllowOveride` docs in detail to limit access more specifically to maximize security. (3) Remember you must restart apache for settings to take effect.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be possible that mod_rewrite is not enabled for the HTTPS server, or that the .htaccess is not being used?

Check the `AllowOveride` permissions in use for the regular site and compare against the SSL version, probably a discrepancy.  Probably introduced to improve security, if not an accident.

`mod_rewrite` is next to essential though, so any decent hosting provider should help sort this out.

Answer (score 1):

"working on apache2 + ubuntu precise"

A similar problem occured to me while I was using *Slim framework* and trying to remove the index.php required in the url. The reWrite worked perfectly for http but for https: it was showing url not found, which meant that the reWrite was not working.

After some hit-n-trial , I came up with this solution:

```
 cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
 sudo vim default-ssl
```

Change AllowOverride None to **All**. 
Similarly **sudo vim ssl**

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, this is what worked for me.

In your httpd.conf, make sure you have both:

ServerName domain.com

ServerAlias www.domain.com