# apache vhost redirect all subdomains to root (SSL vhosts)

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

How to redirect all subdomains to the root domain?

It works for non-SSL domains, but doesn't work for SSL domains!?

eg

```
Works!    
wee.domain.com => https://domain.com
www.domain.com => https://domain.com

Doesn't work! (no redirecting)
https://wee.domain.com => https://domain.com
https://www.domain.com => https://domain.com
```

## vhosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com

    #   force https
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}        off
    RewriteRule ^           https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSA]

    ...

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain.com

    SSLEngine on
    ...

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.domain.com

    RewriteEngine on
    #   Redirect all subdomains to root
    RewriteRule ^           https://domain.com [L,R=301]

    ...

</VirtualHost>

##########   This vhost is not working   ###############

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAlias *.domain.com

    RewriteEngine on
    #   Redirect all subdomains to root
    RewriteRule ^           https://domain.com [L,R=301]

    SSLEngine on
    ...

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Is this solution works for your case ? http://serverfault.com/questions/226908/why-do-htaccess-redirects-work-in-http-but-not-with-https

Answer (score 2):

Add `AllowOverride FileInfo` in the *Directory* clause as below:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/
<Directory /var/www/>
  AllowOverride FileInfo
</Directory>
```